# My .on() is acting like .bind(), not .live()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a complicated nested form (Ryan Bates' version) with `.live()` attached to some of the dynamically generated elements, which I'm now transitioning over to `.on()` along with an upgrade from Jquery 1.4 to 1.7.

Here's  a sample of one of the ~22 changes:

```
# old version with .live()
$('.options .image').live('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked .options')
})

# new version with .on()
$('.options').on('click', '.image', function(){
    console.log('clicked .options')
})
```

The changes work perfectly well for the form elements that already exist but they are failing for any nested elements that are dynamically created afterwards. Hence, it's working more like Jquery's `bind` than `live`. Do you know what might be going on here?

Due to the exceeding complexity of the code and lots of partials I'm leaving it out for now (hoping you might have a hunch!). Thanks.

Comment: have you tried `$(document).on('click', '.image', function(){`

Comment: Could the sequence in which your context appears in the DOM be at issue? Is whatever .options refers to dynamically generated as well?

Comment: @kinakuta - I think you got it (and you were first). Thanks!

Comment: It's not a race... I took my time writing a full explanation for you and any other future readers, sscirrus. ;-)

Comment: @GregPettit - relax Greg, I'll accept one of the detailed answers :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Live has been depreciated anyhow...

Comment: I'm relaxed... that's why I took my time. ;-) If I was anxious, I would've hammered out the fastest answer I could, and then gone back to edit it with more detail later. But nah.

Comment: @GregPettit in any case, just thought I'd thank kinakuta for setting me on the right track. Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per 3nigma's comment but modified with your original selector, this will work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.options .image', function() {
  console.log('clicked .options');
});
```

However, I don't think setting document as listener is usually the way to go. In your original version with `.live()` you are selecting `.image` nodes within the `.options` node.

But the question doesn't say which parts are loaded dynamically. I suspect that `.options` is also part of the content that's loaded dynamically. The first selector when using `.on()` for delegating listeners has to be something that is NOT destroyed:

```
$('#someWrapper').on('click', '.options .image', function() {
  console.log('clicked .options');
});
```

`#someWrapper` doesn't need to be a new wrapper element, it can be any ancestor (what some people call a "parent"... but that's a misnomer since it can be a grandparent or great-grandparent or whatever!) that is not destroyed. The closer to the target selector (.options .image) the better.

Comment: Thanks Greg, a detailed and helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

For your `.on()` code to work, the `.options` element would have to be static - not dynamically created.  The first selector for `.on()` must be a static parent.  It would work just like `.live()` if you used:

```
$(document).on('click', '.options .image', fn);
```

But, your page will perform better if you select a static parent (one that is not created or destroyed) that is closer to the object than the `document` object.  Since you haven't shown us your HTML, I can't recommend a specific object, but presumably, you can pick out the right parent object.

Answer (score 0):

below is the correct syntax of `.on()`  and `.live()`

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

See More:

[`on v/s live`](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/)
[`on and off`](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/)

Comment: `.on()` doesn't have to begin with document.

Comment: @sscirrus. And he wrote it does **?!**

Comment: @gdoron - not explicitly, but providing the syntax of `.on()` didn't answer the question.

Comment: its better to find answer by itself by reading the documents.